# Why does hoisting a string outside a loop result in slower performance?

Tags: c++

In an attempt to refactor loops that where checking for `!eof()` (an anti-pattern), I discovered that the newer code is much slower. See the benchmark here: http://quick-bench.com/hY0cwQzDf7F3cFc-2IlA0JUDf9I

The original code:

```
std::string message("hi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\n");
std::vector<std::string> log_lines;
std::istringstream is(message);

while (!is.eof()) {
  std::string line;
  std::getline(is, line);
  log_lines.emplace_back(std::move(line));
}
```

The newer code:

```
std::string message("hi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\nhi there i am a message whoo hoo\n");
std::vector<std::string> log_lines;
std::istringstream is(message);
std::string line;

while (std::getline(is, line)) {
    log_lines.emplace_back(line);
}
```

As you can see the primary difference is moving `std::string line` outside the loop and changing the loop condition. According to the quick-bench, the newer version is 15x slower using Clang 7.0 with -O3. This seems counter-intuitive, but my theory is that since `std::getline` calls `erase`, it is more expensive to clear the filled string than it is to simply create a new object. Is this theory correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I ran both of these and they do not give the same output (in `log_lines`).

Comment: Also, how were you measuring this? It's possible your benchmark is being optimized away entirely. This can happen e.g. if the compiler determines your function has no side effects and the return value is not used, and can therefore be elided.

Comment: There is no point in comparing performance of two bits of code that give different results.   Your two examples give different output.

Comment: `push_back` is more accurate here, `emplace_back` does the same thing in this code.

Answer (score 3):

In the first program, you move the line into the vector. In the second, you copy it. Copying a string is potentially much slower than moving.